# Clojure failing to compile jackknife

Tags: clojure, leiningen, cascalog

As a clojure noob, I am trying to use cascalog to parse a large CSV file. Here is my minimal project.clj:

```
(defproject org.example/sample "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

  :description "extract fields from a certain csv file."
  :dependencies [
    [cascalog "2.0.0"]
    [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "2.0.1"]
  ]

  :profiles { :dev {:dependencies [[org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core "1.1.2"]]}}

  :jvm-opts ["-Xms768m" "-Xmx768m"]

)
```

`lein deps` succeeds, but when I run `(use 'cascalog.api)` inside `lein repl`, then I get the following error:

`CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: combinations in this context, compiling:(jackknife/seq.clj:12)`

Removing clojure-csv from project.clj prevents the error, but I can run `(use 'clojure-csv.core)` inside `lein repl` without error.

One other person on the internet appears to have had this problem, but has not posted a solution. What is going on here, and how should I fix it? I'd be eternally grateful if someone could help.

Comment: I should mention that my clojure version is 1.3.0 .

Comment: Insert this line in your dependencies: `[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]`. 1.3.0 is really old.